# Play ignore continue 100 requests

Tags: http, playframework

A play Controller with Actions for POST requests, may need to ignore [HTTP Request Automatic Retries](https://blogs.oracle.com/ravello/beware-http-requests-automatic-retries) to prevent Controller code being ran multiple times.

What is the best way to do this in Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

1. add a unique ID to every post request as part of the query string.
2. Extend the `DefaultHttpRequestHandler`, as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers#Extending-the-default-request-handler)
3. In your extension check if this is a request for which you want to
   prevent retries and read the request's ID using `getQueryString` on the `RequestHeader`, see docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.17/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.RequestHeader@getQueryString(key:String):Option[String]).
4. Check if you have already seen the ID by querying a datastore such as Redis. Save the ID to Redis if this is the first time you have seen it.
5. Drop the POST request if you have already seen the ID, otherwise forward it to the router.